# Undefined Method when executing cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I wrote a cucumber scenario with the following steps

```
Scenario: Validate in orders list the order status "Order Creates"
  When I click on the orders button
  And the order "14103795" is visible  
  # Then I can see the screen with the list of orders
  Then I can see the order status "Order Created", the message "Order successfully created", the order date "XXXX", the deliver date "XXXX" or the cancellation date "XXXX".
```

When I run the .feature file, it executes, but i got the following error when the file finishes to run:

```
undefined method `last' for #<String:0x007ffdba07f5e8> (NoMethodError)
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:101:in `execute'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:46:in `execute'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:30:in `around_hook'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:11:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:92:in `block (2 levels) in compose_around_hooks'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:91:in `call'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:91:in `compose_around_hooks'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:22:in `block in describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:17:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:11:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_around_hooks.rb:8:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_after_hooks.rb:5:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_before_hooks.rb:5:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_after_step_hooks.rb:8:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/filters/activate_steps.rb:8:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:11:in `test_case'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:17:in `block in done'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:16:in `each'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:16:in `done'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:61:in `done'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in `done'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:23:in `done'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:31:in `done'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-core-1.2.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:70:in `run!'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:38:in `execute!'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/cucumber-2.0.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/galibon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

And also, the last step does not have the step skeleton created.

Can someone help me with this?

Here is the step definitions

```
When(/^I click on the orders button$/) do
    @orders = Orders.new
    @orders.click_orders
end

When(/^the order "([^"]*)" is visible$/) do |order|
    @orders.locateOrders(order)
end
```

and here are the classes at the page objects that I created

```
def click_orders
    click_link('Pedidos')
    sleep(4)
end

def locateOrders(order)
    exists = false
    while exists == false
        if page.has_content?(order)
            exists=true
            @order_num=order
            puts 'exists'
        elsif page.has_content?(order) == false
            if page.has_content?("Carregar mais pedidos")
                click_button("Carregar mais pedidos")
                sleep(5)
            else
                fail(ArgumentError.new('Pedido não encontrado'))
            end
        end
    end 
end


def order_verify(order_status)
    sleep(3)
    counter = page.all(:xpath, '//*[@id="sh-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div').count
    for i in 1..counter.to_i
        puts i
        within(:xpath, '//*[@id="sh-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div['+i.to_s+']/div'){
            @card_order = find(:xpath, '//*[@id="sh-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div['+i.to_s+']/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]').text
            puts @card_order
        }
        if @card_order == @order_num
            within(:xpath, '//*[@id="sh-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div['+i.to_s+']/div'){


            }
        end
    end
end
```

The last step, witch was going to call the order_verify method, is not generating the skeleton when I run the scenario.

here is my env.rb file

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec'
require 'json'
require 'capybara/cucumber'



include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.default_wait_time = 2
```

Comment: Looks like you are returning a String when you are trying to get back an Array and calling `.last` on that. Update your question with the code snipped that is failing.

Comment: @ColtonFent, here is the update, hope that it helps. Thanks

Comment: That error is inside cucumber and appears to be because the TestStep#source method is returning a string rather than an array.  Are you using any gems that would override/add a  #source method to objects in your system?

Comment: @TomWalpole, here are the gems that i`m using on my env.rb file.


require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec'
require 'json'
require 'capybara/cucumber'

Comment: Its not limited to what you require in env.rb - any gems loaded by the project could be adding #source.  I would debug this by adding a binding.pry or byebug (depending on whatever debugger you're using) call on the line before the error occurs in runner.rb - and then look at the value  of test_step.method(:source).source_location to find out where the source method is defined and why its returning a string and not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Apparently it's a problem with cucumber's version 2.0.2.

I just uninstalled it and installed version 2.0.0 witch uses cucumber-core 1.1.3 and the error stopped occurring. Also it has generated the step skeletons.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use latest Cucumber 2.0.2 and capybara 2.5.0 together, Please make below changes to your 'env.rb' file.

replace this line:

```
 include Capybara::DSL
```

With:

```
World(Capybara::DSL)
```

Why use World()?:  Just to make sure you don't Adulterate the global namespace but still have all the functionality of that module available throughout your scope.

Repeat this for all 'include' statements in env.rb file

e.g. Capybara::RSpecMatchers, Test::Unit::Assertions, etc

Hope this solve your problem, Good Luck!